# Update plot legend after using drawing tools

Tags: plotting, legending, drawing

After manually editing a plot by changing the colours and filling of the curves using the drawing tools, is there any way to update the legend, so that it corresponds with the new colours?

Comment: Why don't you run the Plot function again using the colours and filling you actually want in its options? Manually editing plots as part of your workflow isn't a good idea, usually.

Comment: I'm just getting started with Mathematica, but it seems to me that the options of colouring are limited when you want to enter them in the function, whereas when I edit it I can choose from the whole palet of colours.

Comment: That's not actually true. You can provide any color you like using the `PlotStyle` option. You can choose from color palettes or use color specifications for instance with `RGBColor`

Comment: Great, that's the one I needed! Thanks!